# Topological group closed path

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

A topological group $G$ is a group that is also a topological space in which the maps 
$u:G×G → G$， $v:G→G$ defined by $u(g_1, g_2)=g_1g_2$ and $v(g)=g^{-1}$ are continuous.
Let $f,h$ be closed paths in $G$ based at the Identity element $e$ of $G$. 
Define $f.h$ by $(f.h)(t) = u(f(t),h(t))$ for all $t\in I$.
Show that the homomorphism $v_*:\pi(G,e)→\pi(G,e)$ satisfies $v_*[f]=[f]^{-1}$.

Here is what I think, by definition of the induced homomorphism we know $v_*[f]=[vf]$.
now by the definition of $v_*$ we have $v(f)=f^{-1}$.
hence, $v_*[f]=[vf]=[f^{-1}]$.
so all I need to show is $[f^{-1}]=[f]^{-1}$ if what I have done is correct, but I am having trouble about this.

This exercise is proposed in Kosniowski's "A first course in Algebraic Topology" chapter 15.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f * f^{-1} \sim f\cdot f^{-1} = c_e$ and $f^{-1} * f \sim f^{-1}\cdot f = c_e$, $[f]^{-1} = [f^{-1}]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. may I ask again how do you get your conclusion from the two conditions you wrote? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @user138017 since $f * f^{-1} \sim c_e$, $[f][f^{-1}] = [f * f^{-1}] = [c_e]$. Similarly, since $f^{-1} * f \sim c_e$, $[f^{-1}][f] = [c_e]$. Therefore, $[f]$ is invertible with $[f]^{-1} = [f^{-1}]$.

Comment: @user138017 No problem! :-)

Answer (score 1):

More on this situation  is available in this [paper](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/brown-mucuk-cov.pdf) on covering groups of non-connected topological groups.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the link isn't working.

Comment: @user138017: Seems like the correct link is http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/COV3xy.pdf

Comment: Thanks: both links should  now work.